# android paging library new data inserted to database no update in list

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I don't understand the explanation of Invalidate method, addInvalidateCallback method from official documentation

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/DataSource.html

I am using android arch component paging library but not using Room, when there's new data inserted in my database, do i have to call invalidate ? and then what in order to inserted my new data to the list ? calling setlist on adapter doesnt work, the documentation only show this case for Room usage not for DataSource independent from Room, can anybody help me out ?

below is my data source, i am using sqlite to pull new data, but when w

```
public class ChatPersonalDataSource extends TiledDataSource<MessageItem> {

DataManagerMessage mDataManagerMessage;
String participantHash;
String threadID;

public ChatPersonalDataSource(DataManagerMessage mDataManagerMessage, String participantHash, String threadID) {
    this.mDataManagerMessage = mDataManagerMessage;
    this.participantHash = participantHash;
    this.threadID = threadID;
}

@Override
public int countItems() {
    return DataSource.COUNT_UNDEFINED;
}

private List<MessageItem> toMessageItem(List<Message> messages){
    List<MessageItem> messageItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Message message :
            messages) {
        messageItems.add(new MessageItem(message));
    }
    return messageItems;
}

@Override
public List<MessageItem> loadRange(int startPosition, int count) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<Message> newItems = mDataManagerMessage.getMessageByParticipantHashNonObservable(participantHash, threadID, startPosition, count);
    Timber.d("LOAD RANGE " + gson.toJson(newItems));
    return toMessageItem(newItems);
}}
```

Comment: have you found an answer?? I have the same problem